# How set clip path for children only?

Tags: java, android, draw, android-custom-view, clip

I have a custom view that extends RelativeLayout.
this has many children.
I want clip children only, but my code clipping my custom view too.

```
public class LoadingBox extends RelativeLayout
{

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        save = canvas.save();
          canvas.getClipBounds(clipRect);
          clipRectF.set(clipRect.left, clipRect.top, clipRect.right, 
          clipRect.bottom);
          clipPath.addRoundRect(clipRectF, 40f, 40f, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restoreToCount(save);
    }

}
```

I tested

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){...}
```

too ,but i take this result again.

How i clip child only not self view?

Comment: Please say more (do your drawing before save = canvas.save();)

Comment: now its worse, can write full your idea

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer.
i used below code

```
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_box, this);
```

this is mistake,
must create children view dynamic and override drawChild

```
@Override
protected boolean drawChild(Canvas canvas, View child, long drawingTime)
{
    boolean result;
    canvas.save();
    clipPath.reset();
    canvas.getClipBounds(clipRect);
    clipRectF.set(clipRect.left, clipRect.top, clipRect.right, clipRect.bottom);
    clipPath.addRoundRect(clipRectF, radius-2, radius-2, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
    result = super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
    canvas.restore();
    return result;
}
```